# Reading DOS/Windows Text File in Linux

Tags: vim, line-endings

As you all know, the line endings in DOS/Windows file differ than those of Unix/Linux, so whenever I open a file that I have created using Windows, I see hundreds of ^M after each line. Many people suggested solving this problem using:

```
set fileformat=dos
```

I tried this but it doesn't work, because as far as I noticed, it tells Vim how to "save" the file, rather than how to "read" the file. What I want is keep line-endings as they are, be they Linux, Windows, or MAC, read them correctly, and save the file using the same format aftr editing.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add

   ```
   set fileformats=unix,dos,mac
   ```

   to your vimrc.
2. Run `:e ++ff=dos` in opened file if vim failed to detect correct line ending.

Comment: That is great! So you mean "set fileformats=unix,dos,mac" should do the job, but in my case it is failing to detect correct line endings? Why would it fail? I don't see anything hard in detecting line ends, especially for an advanced editor like Vim.

Comment: @Rafid K. Abdullah If I remember correctly, it fails with mixed LF/CRLF line endings.

Answer (score 0):

```
" put this in your ~/.vimrc, resource then and try :Dos2Unix
" dos2unix ^M
fun! Dos2unixFunction()
    let _s=@/
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    try
        set ff=unix
        w!
        "%s/\%x0d$//e
    catch /E32:/
        echo "sorry, first save your file."
    endtry
    let @/=_s
    call cursor(l, c)
endfun
com! Dos2Unix keepjumps call Dos2unixFunction()
```